# how to print [][]interface{} in go?

Tags: json, go

i am trying to print the data from this page: https://www.rolimons.com/api/activity

this is how it looks:

```
{"success":true,"activities":[[1624720645,1,6815676017,1080,1047,563399],[1624720637,1,6807138720,915,893,563398],[1624720633,1,6803395856,683,687,563397],[1624720633,1,2409285794,44853,44867,563396],[1624720623,1,71484026,2172,2114,563395],[1624720613,1,9254254,6620,6632,563394],[1624720611,1,124472052,1054,1048,563393],[1624720581,1,6803403781,671,653,563392],[1624720578,1,44113968,972,980,563391],[1624720527,1,332772333,2274,2264,563390]],"activities_count":10}
```

i used https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/
to get:

```
type data struct {
    Success         bool            `json:"success"`
    Activities      [][]interface{} `json:"activities"`
    ActivitiesCount int             `json:"activities_count"`
}
```

this is my code:

```
    resp, err := http.Get("https://www.rolimons.com/api/activity")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    var data *data
    error := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&data)
    if error != nil {
        panic(error)
    }
    println(data.Activities)
```

but it gives me this:

```
[11/13]0xc0002bc000
```

but i want to make it print the 4th and the 5th value for example:

```
{"success":true,"activities":[[1624720645,1,6815676017,1080,1047,563399]
```

would be:

```
1080,1047
```

Comment: `fmt.Println(data.Activities[0][3], data.Activities[0][4])` What do you have problems with exactly?

Comment: thank you that was the solution, idk how you did it but thanks.

Comment: The builtin function `println` has limited functionality. Use `fmt.Println(data)` to print all of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in this [example](https://play.golang.org/p/gLJQeMX2oPI), you can use `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", data.Activities)` to print the data of that slice.

To print only the wanted cell, use indices to address them.

You can address slice indices with square braces `[]` like so:
`data.Activities[0][4]` to access the 5th element of the first nested slice.